# Intl.DateTimeFormat does not output separators on 2 digit month + day (IE 11)

Tags: javascript, intl

I have encountered a bug in `Intl.DateTimeFormat` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

**Environment**

Internet Explorer 11.0.6900.19080 on Windows 7

**Bug**

When only the "2-digit" option is used for month + day the function is not outputting any separators, be it `/` for `en` or `.` for `de`. This happens only in Internet Explorer on Windows 7. Internet Explorer 11 + Edge on Windows 10 is working. Not tested lower than 11.

> Internet Explorer

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).format(new Date());
> "‎07‎ ‎25"

Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).format(new Date());
> "‎07‎/‎25‎/‎2018"
```

> Chrome

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).format(new Date());
> "07/25"

Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).format(new Date());
> "07/25/2018"
```

**Context**

I have used `react-intl` when this error occurred and traced the error back to the native `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`

```js
<FormattedDate
    value={new Date()}
    month="2-digit"
    day="2-digit"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=DateTimeFormat) `DateTimeFormat` full support was added to IE11 on released version `oct 17 ,2013`, so it might be that your Windows 7 has an older version, you can check this by clicking on the link beside the version number.

[image]

To fix your issue, you can

- Update IE11 (I don't think it is a solution) this will work only for you
- Add the separator manually according to your app supported languages

```js
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit"
  })
  .format(new Date()).split(" ").join("/");
```

- Use the following [polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/) to get full support

Comment: I have a version from July 10, 2018

Comment: @MarvinFischer this version on windows 7? could please try the polyfill I have shared

Comment: The polyfill works, but a polyfill is not the way I'd want to go for a feature that should be natively supported

Comment: @MarvinFischer isn't this the purpose of polyfills ?!!!! a piece of code that provides the technology that you, the developer, expect the browser to provide natively.

Comment: Yes in the case the browser does not already natively support it. But the browser I am using does indeed support this feature natively. Just seemingly failed at its integration